# javafx-2, connect a TableView to a regular bean, that is a bean whose fields don't provide Property s

Tags: tableview, javafx-2

My table view:

```
TableView<Person> = new TableView<Person>();
```

but person is something like:

```
class Person {

    String firstName;

    public getFirstName() {return firstName;}
```

}

that is it has not the new javafx style properties. It is an existing class, instantiated by the library I use.

I create the column with the following code:

```
TableColumn columnFirstName = new TableColumn("First Name");

columnCodfis.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person,   String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Person, String> arg) {
            if (arg.getValue()==null) return null;
            return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(arg.getValue().firstName);
        }
    });
```

It is quite cumbersome, but works. 
My **questions** are:

1. it is pointless returning an ObservableValue, since the bean isn't able to fire change events. Thus, i would like to avoid all the ObservableValue overhead, how to do it?
2. since the javabean won't fire events by itself, i need some old-fashioned resfresh events, like fireCellUpdate. Is it such a method?

Answer (score 2):

For the first point, I don't think you can.

For the second point, I don't think you can, either. Not directly anyway.
I think the best solutions would be to use a [JavaBeanStringProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/adapter/JavaBeanStringProperty.html) to wrap the `firstname` property and to call `fireValueChangedEvent()` each time you want to udpdate the cell.